# Does Flask-Sqlalchemy support Mutable tracking?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'd like my dstabase models to contain mutable dictionaries. Is this possible with flask-sqlalchemy? If so, can you please provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database supports it, you can use [`JSON`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON) column type. Currently this is supported in:

- PostgreSQL
- MySQL as of version 5.7
- SQLite as of version 3.9

Your dictionaries will have to be serializable, of course.